# Why do screw head sizes and lengths vary for a stated size?

Tags: drywall, screws

I have two #8 screws, they should have the same diameter. They are supposed to be 1-1/4" long, but one is slightly longer. I don't care too much about it. However, the heads of the two screws, both being round, have different diameters. The bigger the head, the better coverage of the screw when used. I'm wondering the difference is caused by errors in manufacture, or there are in fact different screw head sizes.

Comment: Can you upload a picture showing the two screws next to a ruler?

Comment: How different are the heads?  Are we talking 1 mm, or is one twice the size of the other?

Comment: There are several different kinds of “round head” screws, including pan, round and button (see here: https://cadsetterout.com/resources/wood-screw-head-types/). Photos would help identify the types you have.

Comment: Did they come out of the same box? How do you know they're both #8? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: There are of course different screw head sizes, as you can see. This parameter is not always specified on consumer packaging.